# Python module caffe.io doesn't work

Tags: python, caffe, deep-dream

I have Ubuntu 16.04 with installed Python 2.7 and 3.5.
I've got Caffe from repository and successfully compiled, all tests are passed.

When I work in Terminal I can import caffe module and it has "io":

```
>>> import caffe
>>> caffe.io
<module 'caffe.io' from 'caffe/io.pyc'>
```

But when I use PyCharm "io" is absent:

```
    model = caffe.io.caffe_pb2.NetParameter()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'io'
```

Code example that I'm trying to run is here https://github.com/google/deepdream/blob/master/dream.ipynb

Comment: check whether you are using correct python interpreter in pycharm

Comment: What output does `print(caffe)` produce? You almost certainly have a local `caffe.py` file that is masking the installed library.

Comment: @mic4ael: more importantly, the correct module; `import caffe` worked after all.

Comment: Also, in future, please paste console output as text, which makes it searchable and for us that try to help you, copyable. Next, a *full traceback* is appreciated, because common errors like naming your script `caffe.py` will immediately be visible in such a traceback.

Comment: @martijn-pieters thanks, there is local caffe.py file in the project

Answer (score 0):

The reason is local caffe.py file.
thanks @martijn-pieters for your comment